# Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar) exception when refreshing WebBrowser object

Tags: c#, windows-ce

We have a device running Microsoft CE v6.0 with an application running under i think around .NET 2.5.

We have a peculiar way of displaying some information on the screen of the device by using a `WebBrowser` object and a locally stored html page.

Essentially we do this:

```
//Create a WebBrowser object
public WebBrowser htmlUserText = new WebBrowser(); // Initialization in main form
SetupInternalControl(htmlUserText, pnlCenterDisplay); 


// Set up a default html file and point the web browser at it. 
htmlFile = new StreamWriter("\\Temp\\HtmlText.html");
htmlFile.Write("<html><body scroll=no bgcolor = #646464><font color = #FFFFFF>");
htmlFile.Close();
htmlUserText.Navigate(new Uri("\\Temp\\HtmlText.html")); // This is a constant file we create some default stuff in it. 
htmlUserText.Visible = false;

// At some point we can write some html to the file and after it is closed we do this:
htmlUserText.Refresh();
htmlUserText.Visible = true;
htmlUserText.BringToFront();
```

The affect in previous versions of windows ce, was that the webpage was displayed:

Here is an example html file and result:

```
<html><body scroll=no bgcolor = #646464><font color = #FFFFFF>lalalalalalala
```

[image]

Now however when i try the same thing, I get an `Exception` with the following stack trace:

```
>Error
>Exception
>at
>Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)
>at
>System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Refresh()
>at ....
```

I have read similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495581/targetinvocationexception-microsoft-agl-common-misc-handlearpal-error-ar), but my problem seems to be specific to this refresh, and i am not familiar with the remainder of the code and resources are opened / not cleaned up. I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655662/how-to-ignore-script-errors-in-webbrowser) but ignoring script errors doesn't do anything.

I cant step through the code since its running on an external device and has no connection to my pc. When i `try catch` around the `refresh()` line i get an Exception but it is not helpful at all, it has no inner exception and the message is just `"Exception"`.

1. **Is there anything very obviously bad with they way this code was implemented. I know it may not be optimal but im not looking to change legacy code if i don't have to.**
2. **How can i get more detailed information about why this is happening so i can track it down?**

---

Even if remove the refresh and just navigate to and display the page, we do not get an exception thrown but the web page is not shown, we simply get a white background with nothing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a very very misleading bug.

The product that CE is running on is a KEBA keTop Pendant. KEBA releases different firmware and OS versions for CE on their machines. When upgrading the pendant I upgraded from 1.2 PRO to 1.3 Standard. **The standard version does not include Internet Explorer**. As far as i can tell, IE is important when viewing web pages (*sarcasm*).

The solution here was to upgrade to 1.4 PRO.

It is interesting that the `WebBrowser` Exception did not have any knowledge of the fact that IE was missing.